# how to check if list is empty

Tags: sml, smlnj

just started learning sml so excuse me for any discomfort that i may cause.

Okay so here is my function:

```
fun swapPairsInList [(x,y)]
swapPairsInList: (’x * ’y) list --> (’y * ’x) list
```

I know how to swap the pairs in the list (recursively) but where i'm having issues is with the base case on when the list is empty (null). How exactly do i check if this list is null? I tried

```
null [(x,y)]
```

but that's just throwing back an exception. Should i be using pattern matching to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you used `null` and what the exception was? The expression `null [(x,y)]` should not cause any type of error as long as `x` and `y` are in scope. However it will also never return true because the list `[(x,y)]` is clearly not empty.

Comment: Hm.. is my function parameter incorrectly stated then? What i'm trying to do is pass a list of tuples to swapPairsInList and have the tuple pairs be swapped. For example: calling `swapPairsInList [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)];` would return `[(2,1),(4,3),(6,5)]`

Comment: Yes, if your code looks like `fun swapPairsInList [(x,y)] = something`, then your code is wrong because it will only work with lists that contain exactly one element. For more information I'd need to see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i figured it out, I was attacking the problem from the wrong angle once i looked at the map function located in the [ListPair structure](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list-pair.html#SIG%3aLIST_PAIR.map%3aVAL)

New code:

```
fun swap (x,y) = (y,x);
fun pairSwap l = map swap l;
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference:

```
fun swapPairsInList []            = []
  | swapPairsInList ((x,y)::tail) = (y,x) :: swapPairsInList tail
```

The pattern `[]` matches the empty list.

Of course, using higher order functions like map and foldl is much nicer.